# Issues creating runnable jar files

Tags: java, linux, executable-jar

I've been spending quite a bit of time trying to create executable jar files on linux. I can run jar files that I've downloaded by just double clicking on them, however when I try to do the same with jar files I create either with intellij or through the command line, I can't just open it by double clicking. I have to open a terminal and then run "java -jar jarfile.jar". It's not anything to do with default apps (I'm pretty sure) because both the jar files I've downloaded (e.x. ATLauncher) and the jar files I make have both been set to open with java 21.0.1.

Comment: Does [this](https://technojeeves.com/tech/f.jar) work with double-click? (shows a small empty window only)

Comment: How are you creating the jars? Which desktop environment are you using.

Comment: I'm using linux mint Cinnamon, and I'm using the following commands to compile: `javac Test.java` Then `jar -cfm Test.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF *.class` the manifest's contents are `Manifest-Version: 1.0` `Main-Class: Test`.

Comment: That would only work if you have a manifest file at that relative path. But you don't need to use a manifest explicitly for simple cases. Use `cfe` switches as shown elsewhere on this page. `jar cfe Test.jar Test *.class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick test.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShowVersion{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("hello world");
        frame.add( new JLabel("java version: " + System.getProperty("java.version")));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

That will create a window and show the java version. Compile it.

```
javac --target 8 --source 8 ShowVersion.java
```

That will make a version that works with java as old as java 8. Then create an executable jar file.

```
jar cfe app.jar ShowVersion ShowVersion.class
```

I expect the resulting jar file should run, and confirm if you're using the java you think you are.

Comment: This works now. The version it tells me is 21.0.1, so the other ones should have worked fine. I think I'll try recompiling my code with the `--target 8 --source 8` options and seeing if that works. Thank you for the help!